# Parallel Access to Elements in a Groovy List

Tags: data-structures, groovy, concurrency

This is a simple efficiency question around the Groovy language; I have a `Customer` object that within it has an `id` and I would like to transfer those IDs into another list which in my view is atomic so can be paralleled.

e.g. linear execution

```
public List<Long> extractIds(List<Customer> customerList) {
    List<Long> customerIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    customerList.each { it -> customerIds.add(it.id) }
}
```

**Question**: What is the most efficient way to transfer the IDs in the above example when holding a large volume of customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method would be:

```
public List<Long> extractIds(List<Customer> customerList) {
    customerList.id
}
```

Or, if you want to do it in a multi-threaded fashion, you can use gpars:

```
import static groovyx.gpars.GParsPool.withPool

public List<Long> extractIds(List<Customer> customerList) {
    withPool {
        customerList.collectParallel { it.id }
    }
}
```

But you may find the first brute-force method is quicker for this simple example (rather than spinning up a thread pool, and synchronizing the collection of results from different threads)

Comment: I did not know about the first method - my love of Groovy grows by the minute!